# Jquery mobile app header showing in full page in some mobile phones

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have developed an Android App using Jquery Mobile. It contains a Header which has a background image in it. In some mobile phones, the app is working perfect. But in some phones, only the header containing the background image is displayed in the whole screen and nothing happens. It does not display the rest of the content of the page. Here is the code for the page:-

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo</title> 
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />    




<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />



<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script type='application/javascript' src='js/fastclick.js'></script>



</head>
<body >

<div data-role="page" class="content" data-theme='b'>

<div  data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-theme='b'>
<div class="ui-grid-solo">
<div class="ui-block-a"><div class="logodiv"><img height="100%" width="100%" src="img/logo2.png" /></div> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
Some Content here
Some Content here
Some Content here
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS is as follows:-

```
.ui-page
{
    background-color: #EBEAF2;
}
.ui-header
{
    background-color: #EBEAF2!important;    
}
body 
{
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: moz-none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.content 
{
    background-image: url(img/bg.png);
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 300px 300px;
    background-position: center; 
    }
body
{
  background-image: img/bcklogo.png;
}

  body ,h1 , h2 ,h3,h4,h5,h6
{
  font-family: 'Roboto',serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have skipped writing data-role content and also one div does not close properly.

```
Also in class logodiv you need to provide header height.

Please check this code below

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo</title> 
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />    




<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />



<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<style> 

.ui-page
{
    background-color: #EBEAF2;
}
.ui-header
{
    background-color: #EBEAF2!important;    
}
body 
{
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: moz-none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.content 
{
    background-image: url(img/img.png);
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 300px 300px;
    background-position: center; 
    }
body
{
  background-image: img/img.png;
}

  body ,h1 , h2 ,h3,h4,h5,h6
{
  font-family: 'Roboto',serif;
}

.logodiv {
height: 80px;
}
</style>


</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" class="content" data-theme='b'>

<div  data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-theme='b'>
<div class="ui-grid-solo">
<div class="ui-block-a"><div class="logodiv"><img height="100%" width="100%" src="img/img.png" /></div> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
Some Content here
Some Content here
Some Content here
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok.. I corrected that data-role=content and closing the div part. But the problem still persists. That means the problem is because of not specifying header height. I want to ask that if I specify the header height to be 80px as in your code above, will the header be responsive. Will my app work in all phones now? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No it wont be responsive you need to either handle it via the media queries or even better put em. For example if the specification says header needs to be 80px for iphone 2x (device pixel ratio 2), then you need to give height as 80/2 = 40/16 [font size for header text] = 2.5em, so this will be 80px in all devices since you have calculated the base em and applying it in css.